# What is the way of changing a home directory of a user in Cerberus FTP Server?

Tags: windows

What is the way of changing a home directory of a user in [Cerberus FTP Server](https://www.cerberusftp.com)?

I have a user, but I can't change the direct login to that user to a specific folder. Can somebody help me?